# PHP not rendering newlines in content retrieved from database

Tags: php, string, content-management-system, whitespace

My own CMS is nearing completion but for some reason the article view page does not show newlines in the   content when retrieving from the database.

The newlines display fine in the "edit post" window after creation so they are being saved correctly.

I am passing the content through htmlspecialchars() when it is retrieved so what could be going wrong?

Thanks,
Ilmiont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You propably need a `$content = nl2br($content)` after your htmlspecialchars call to convert the real line breaks to html line breaks.

Comment: Great thanks... new to PHP so didn't know that existed. Done as nl2br(htmlspecialchars($content)) to keep it compact :)